# Change the color and size of characters of selected cells (and come back to the initial state if unselected)

Tags: excel, vba, events

I try to develop a small macro with the event worksheet_selectionChange in order that when I select a cell, I would like that the characters inside become a bit bigger and  the color of the cell becomes green. Then when I unselect the cell to select another cell, I would like that the unselected cell comes back to the initial state( it means no color, size of characters like exactly before the selection of the cell)... apparently my macro does exactly what I want for the size of the character (the size of characters changes when I select the cell and when I unselect it, the size of the characters of the cell comes back exactly like it was before the selection). However for the color it does not work like I would like, indeed the macro changes the color of the cell (in green) when I select it but when I unselect it (to select another cell), the color remains inside the cell... Please find my vba code below (PS:I placed this code only in one sheet of my excel file (Sheet1) because I would like that this code is applicable only to this sheet in my file, thanks in advance for your help.Xavi

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    LargeSize = FontSize * 1.2
    Cells.Font.Size = FontSize
    ActiveCell.Font.Size = LargeSize
    ActiveCell.Font.Size = LargeSize

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Const FontSize As Integer = 12
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    LargeSize = FontSize * 1.2
    With Cells
        .Font.Size = FontSize
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With
    With Target
        .Font.Size = LargeSize
        .Interior.Color = 49407
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very Dy.Lee but unfortunately, this code does not work, I have an error message when I select a cell in my sheet:  "run time error 1004: unable to set the size of property of the Font class"

Comment: @Xavi, Have you set FontSize?

Comment: thanks a lot Dy.Lee! now it works perfectly, I understand the logic also, you defined LargeSize as constant, otherwise the code can not work...